# xcopy to copy the content from system to remote location

Tags: task, scheduler, xcopy

I need a xcopy command to copy the files from one system to remote location.
My concerns are:
I thought to schedule a task in task scheduler on every day.
So in destination it needs to create a folder with name as "test_(currentdate)".The current date has to be the current system date.no need of time.Inside the folder the source file has to be copied.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

first, make the directory on the other computer that contains the file that you want to recieve shared.

then, copy all in bold text into a text file, name the file with an 'appropriate name.bat.
When required just run it.

---

```
@ECHO OFF
```

net use x: /delete 
net use x: serverfalcondata_collectionzipped

xcopy /E /I x:falcondata_collectionzipped*.* d:backup_directory